# Как использовать библиотеку lz4 в cgo на Mac OS Ventura

Tags: c++, golang, m1

при попытке скомпилировать cgo на Mac os`и получаю следующую ошибку, хотя устанавливал через brew lz4 (подозреваю это просто утилита)

```
mycode.c...: fatal error: 'lz4.h' file not found
```

на линуксах все просто, это решается следующим образом:

```
yum install -y gcc gcc-c++ zlib-devel lz4-devel
```

заранее скажу что я знаю, что cgo плохо, cgo не для маков и тд. Скорее ищу людей которые возможно умеют такое обходить без виртуализаций и тд или объяснения почему это невозможно.

Comment: cgo не плохо. Однако вопрос бестолковый. lz4 используется также как и любая другая библиотека С/C++. Указывайте компилятору, где искать заголовочные файлы, линкеру - где лежат библиотеки, и что линковать.

Comment: Вы пробовали https://github.com/pierrec/lz4? Я попробовал в Linux - работае без установки заголовков, нужна только бинарная библиотека

Comment: @PakUula , еще нет, но сейчас попробую

Comment: @user7860670, вопрос скорее про то как сделать это удобно чтобы не уметь отличать при разработке Mac os и linux и соберется ли эта библиотека под M1 архитектуру? Кажется очень глубокое погружение для достаточно поверхностной задачи

Answer (score 1):

чтобы избавиться от данной ошибки можно напрямую установить lz4

```
$ git clone https://github.com/lz4/lz4
$ cd lz4 
$ sudo make install
```